# How do I handle USSD responses with delphi 10.4?

Tags: android, delphi, telephonymanager, accessibilityservice, ussd

How do I handle USSD responses with delphi 10.4?

I work with an Android 7 and 9 device. My goal is to manage the USSD dialogue with my application.

- I send the first request USSD #111*1*6*1# to ask for my balance.
- The android system sends back a text asking for the secret code.

I would like to grab this answer and customize it by my application. Also to send by my own application the secret code.
I found a similair example in android studio on the following link:
http://umeshisran4android.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-readparse-ussd-messages.html

Please, does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is that you translate the Java code into Delphi code. The long answer is that this takes considerable skill, experience and time.

Comment: I've posted some clues in reply to your original question in Delphi Praxis: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/5323-is-it-possible-to-create-on-delphi-my-own-accessibility-service/?do=findComment&comment=46398

Comment: @DaveNottage Phew!